# Angular/NGRX: Strange behaviour with entity and selectAll?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

`seletAll` from `getSelectors()` fire event without change into own feature store, but when the root store changes.

Open the the demo and click on the button. The button dispatch a change into the root store, but selectAll from the feature store also fire the event:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngrx-test-123654789-a7js8p?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffeatures%2Fbar.component.ts

[image]

this behaviour happens only if `seletAll` is used into other selector that accept props as parameter.

seletAll should fire events only when the changes comes into the feature store.

This is the selectors:

```
export const selectBarStore = createFeatureSelector<State>('barStore');

export const selectBarState = createSelector(
  selectBarStore,
  (state: State) => state ? state.bar : null
);

export const { selectEntities, selectAll } = adapter.getSelectors(selectBarState);

export const selectBarById = createSelector(
  selectAll,
  (itemEntities: Bar[], props: {id: number}) =>
  itemEntities ? itemEntities.filter(element => element.id === props.id) : []
);
```

**UPDATE 1**:

I have also opened an issue on ngrx github https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2707

A ngrx developer say

> I'm not sure if this is a bug, and if it is a bug, how to fix it.
> The root cause is the props selector, which shares the same selectAll instance (because it passes down the props to selectAll).

**UPDATE 2**

The workaround is make the selector a factory and DON'T pass props parameter:

BEFORE

```
export const selectBarById = createSelector(
  selectAll,
  (itemEntities: Bar[], props: {id: number}) =>
  itemEntities ? itemEntities.filter(element => element.id === props.id) : []
);
```

AFTER

```
export const selectBarById = (id: number) => createSelector(
  selectAll,
  (itemEntities: Bar[]) =>
  itemEntities ? itemEntities.filter(element => element.id === id) : []
);
```

**The main question is: It is a NGRX bug or I'm doing wrong something?**

Comment: Strange one. I tried a whole bunch of stuff on that StackBlitz and couldn't figure it out. It appears to be a bug.